# How to specify constraints when defining data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I understand the principle of "making illegal states unrepresentable" in functional languages, but I often have troubles putting it in practice.

As an example, I am trying to define a trading book model. I've defined these data types:

```hs
data Side = Buy | Sell
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Order =
    Order
    {
      orderSide      :: Side
    , orderQuantity  :: Int
    , orderPrice     :: Float
    }
    deriving (Eq)

data Book =
    Book
        { buy  :: [Order]
        , sell :: [Order]
        }
    deriving (Show)
```

Basically, meaning that a `Book` is a type with two lists of orders, one per side.

However, this is perfectly valid:

```hs
ghci> o = Order Sell 10 92.22
ghci> Book [o] []
Book {buy = [Order {orderSide = Sell, orderQuantity = 10, orderPrice = 92.22}], sell = []}
```

And it is also perfectly wrong.

How can I express the constraint that only `Buy` orders should go to the buy side, and `Sell` orders on the other?

Comment: First you should consider whether there's any need to have an explicit field or type distinction between buys and sells at all, since both are just ways of looking at the same thing from different sides: a _transaction_.

Comment: True, but there's some sort of asymmetricity that the side would encode. For instance, a buy order is more aggressive the more its price _increases_, whereas a sell order is more aggressive the more its price _decreases_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in many different ways, but I think this is the simplest:

```
data OrderInfo =
    OrderInfo
    {
      orderQuantity  :: Int
    , orderPrice     :: Float
    }
    deriving (Eq)

data BuyOrder = BuyOrder OrderInfo
data SellOrder = SellOrder OrderInfo

data Book =
    Book
        { buy  :: [BuyOrder]
        , sell :: [SellOrder]
        }
    deriving (Show)
```

Unfortunately, that makes it impossible to write general functions that works on both sell and buy orders. You could recover that ability by introducing another type and some straightforward conversion functions:

```
data Side = Buy | Sell
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data SomeOrder = SomeOrder Side OrderInfo

fromBuy :: BuyOrder -> SomeOrder
fromSell :: SellOrder -> SomeOrder
buyOrSell :: SomeOrder -> Either BuyOrder SellOrder
```

You can avoid that overhead by using GADTs and DataKinds:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Side = Buy | Sell
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data SSide a where
  SBuy :: SSide Buy
  SSell :: SSide Sell
deriving instance Show (SSide a)
deriving instance Eq (SSide a)

data Order side =
    Order
    {
      orderSide      :: SSide side
    , orderQuantity  :: Int
    , orderPrice     :: Float
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Book =
    Book
        { buy  :: [Order Buy]
        , sell :: [Order Sell]
        }
    deriving Show
```

Comment: Very reasonable, but I would suggest `newtype` instead of `data` for the wrappers.

Comment: @Noughtmare Just to see if I understand this correctly: `SSide` is a type parametrised on `Side`. `Order` is a type parametrised on `SSide`, so to create an order we now need to write `(Order SSell) 10 92.22`. But I still don't get why `buy` (or `sell`) in `Book` are of type `[Order Buy]` (or `Sell`) and not `[Order SBuy]` (or `SSell`).

Comment: `Order` is a type constructor parameterized by `Side`, but also a term constructor parameterized by `SSide` (and `Int` and `Float`). So when you use it as a type you have to apply it to a `Side` as in `Order Buy`, but when you construct a term then you have to use the singleton `SSide` as in `o = Order SSell 10 92.22`.

Comment: Thank you. That makes things clearer... though I must admit the learning curve never seems to plateau here! :D

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a radical change of representation:

```
data Transaction = Transaction
    { quantity :: Int
    , price :: Float
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

newtype Book = Book [Transaction]
-- or perhaps type Book = [Transaction], depending on context

buyOrder :: Int -> Float -> Transaction
-- or buyOrder :: Word -> Float -> Transaction if you are paranoid
buyOrder q p = Transaction q p

sellOrder :: Int -> Float -> Transaction
sellOrder q p = Transaction (-q) p
```

You can still recover which direction a transaction is going, if it's *really* necessary (seems like it shouldn't really be necessary, but I could be wrong):

```
isBuyOrder :: Transaction -> Bool
isBuyOrder = (>0) . quantity
```